# Django Handle Anonymous user in status check

Tags: python, django

i want to make this function working with the AnonymousUser but dont know who to properly filter for AnonymousUser at the status line:

```
def post_sell_multiple_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post_Sell_Multiple, pk=pk)
    list_comments = Post_Sell_Multiple_Comment.objects.get_queryset().filter(post_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    status = Post_Paid_Sell_Multiple.objects.filter(user=request.user, post_id=pk, status=1).count()
    paginator = Paginator(list_comments, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('commentpage')
    comments = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'app/Post_Sell_Multiple/post_sell_multiple_detail.html',
                  {'post': post,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'status': status
                   })
```

With a user i created its working fine but not with the AnonymousUser. Currently i get the following error here:

> TypeError at /post/1/sell_multiple
>
> 'AnonymousUser' object is not
> iterable

Kind regards

Comment: Does it make sense to render such page if the user is not logged in? Otherwise you should add a `@login_required` decorator on the view.

Comment: That would be one possible solution, yes but it would also disable visitors to checkout the preview content of a paid post so not a pratical idea here.

Comment: well the question is more what do you want to happen if no user has logged in, since the filter `user=request.user` does not make much sense then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `user.is_authenticated` to check if user is logged in, do filter based on that:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post_Sell_Multiple, pk=pk)
list_comments = Post_Sell_Multiple_Comment.objects.get_queryset().filter(post_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
if request.user.is_authenticated:
     status = Post_Paid_Sell_Multiple.objects.filter(user=request.user, post_id=pk, status=1).count()
else:
     status =  Post_Paid_Sell_Multiple.objects.filter(post_id=pk, status=1).count()
paginator = Paginator(list_comments, 10)
page = request.GET.get('commentpage')
comments = paginator.get_page(page)
return render(request, 'app/Post_Sell_Multiple/post_sell_multiple_detail.html',
                  {'post': post,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'status': status
                   })
```

Comment: Thx. that what i needed expect that status=0 has to be set at the second line of status. Trought it would be more complicated. thx again.